# Could not find or load main class (when compiling with dependencies)

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile Java file with dependencies.

This file has inside:

```
package assignment3;
public class CandyLearner {
```

This is my directory tree:

```
../
├── lib
│   └── learnlib-0.9.1-dependencies-bundle.jar
├── src
│   └── assignment3
│       ├── CandyLearner.java
│       ├── CandyLearner.java~
│       └── SutSocketWrapper.java
```

I am inside `src/` and I run:

```
java -cp .:../lib/learnlib-0.9.1-dependencies-bundle.jar assignment3.CandyLearner
```

and I get error: `Error: Could not find or load main class assignment3.CandyLearner`

Tried many solutions posted in SO but can't make it compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use

```
javac
```

to compile code  and

```
java
```

to run the compiled program.

I suggest you use an IDE as this will set up the project so you can compile&run it with one button.

Comment: correct, somehow i missed this completely.. Thanks :)